# I keep getting this error when i use intstream in java, it says

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I keep getting the errors Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression
    - Syntax error on token ">", invalid (
    - x cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token ">", invalid (
    - x cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public Neuron adjust(){
    Neuron neuron = new Neuron(layerType());
    IntStream.range(0, weights.length).forEach(x -> neuron.weights[x]=weights[x] + Math.random()-0.5);
    neuron.threshold=threshold+Math.random()-0.5;
    return neuron;
}
```

Comment: it is java 1.7, I am using eclipse

Comment: do you know if I can overcome this in eclipse, or will i have to get java 8?

Comment: That will never work in Java 7, Streams came with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses streams and lambda functions which are new features of Java 8.  Those errors are what I'd expect to see if you try to compile that code using Java 7, or with the "1.7 compiler compliance level" that some Java 8 IDEs offer.

You have a couple of options.

1. Get Java 8.  I thoroughly recommend this.  It's got a lot of really nice features that aren't in earlier versions of Java.  It's been around for a few years now, and there's really no good reason not to be using it for all your Java development.
2. Rewrite your code using features that were available in Java 7.  The line of code that's giving you all those errors could be written as follows.

.

```
 for( int x = 0; x < weights.length; x++ ) { 
     neurons.weights[x] = weights[x] + Math.random() - 0.5;
 }
```

Frankly, I'd write the code this way, even if I were using Java 8.  Most people would find the `for` loop easier to read than the line of code that you've written.  There's no point in using streams and lambdas when a simple, clear `for` loop will do the trick.